# Magento 2 How to add Customer attribute to Reports => Customer => Order Total grid

Tags: reports, magento2.4.5

I had created new customer attribute Reward ID and I need this custom attribute in the Reports => Customer => Order Total grid and csv.
Please let me know how can i do this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you will need to extend the `vendor/magento/module-reports/view/adminhtml/layout/reports_report_customer_orders_grid.xml` and add your custom column. You can add it in your custom module adminhtml layout or your adminhtml theme folder.

```
       <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.reward_id" as="reward_id">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reward ID</argument>
                <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">reward_id</argument>
                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">reward_id</argument>
                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-reward_id</argument>
                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-reward_id</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

Then you will need to get the reward_id in the grid report collection.
As the order collection is used, the best solution will to save the customer's reward_id in the sales_order table when an order is placed.

Afterwards you will need to extend the _joinFields function of the class `vendor/magento/module-reports/Model/ResourceModel/Customer/Totals/Collection.php` and add a similar function to joinCustomerName to join your reward_id.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nikolas. This helped me a lot. Thank you.